# Looking for suggestions. Javascript object data to xls

Tags: javascript, apache, jasper-reports

I´ve a Javascript object with all the data that I need to store on xls file. What could be the better way? Apache POI? Jasper-Reports? I´m not sure about the correct choice. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to import it with Excel I would suggest creating an [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) out of the data instead.

This can easily be done with JavaScript and Excel can import that format.